# CSV file reader in PHP that supports large files (>15k lines)

Tags: php, file, csv, performance

I have written the following function in PHP to read a CSV file. It works correctly for small files.

However, if I try to read in files that are bigger than 15k lines, it takes between 1–2 minutes to process them. How can I optimize this code to make it run faster on large files?

Is there anything else that I should improve?

```
function read_csv($file){
        $return_waarde = array();
        if(!is_null($file) && !is_empty($file)){
            $header = str_getcsv(utf8_encode(array_shift($file)), ';'); 
            $header_trimmed = array();

            foreach($header as $value){
                $trim = trim($value);
                if(!in_array($value, $header_trimmed)){
                    $header_trimmed[] = $trim;
                } else {
                    $header_trimmed[] = $trim . "1";
                }
            }
            ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
            ini_set('max_execution_time', '180');

            foreach($file as $record)
            {
                if(!in_array($record,$return_waarde)){
                    $return_waarde[] = array_combine($header_trimmed, str_getcsv(utf8_encode($record), ';'));
                }
            }
        } else {
            $return_waarde = "there is no file";
        }
        return $return_waarde;
    }
```

Comment: Sometime back, I had answered on SO,  which used to read csv, and returns multidimensional array, may help you, here is link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876031/create-multidimensional-associative-array-from-csv-in-php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Performance

As performance is your main concern, let's face this first. To complete the example CSV-file with *~36k lines* your original script needs around **139s**<sup>*</sup>.

The main bottlenecks are `in_array`:

```
if (!in_array($record,$return_waarde)) {}
```

and `array_combine`:

```
$return_waarde[] = array_combine($header_trimmed, str_getcsv(utf8_encode($record), ';'));
```

As you want an associative array, we can't get rid of `array_combine` but we can improve the very expensive and slow test from `in_array`.

**Idea**

Instead of checking the fastly growing and complex result-array for existence of the newly created associative array, you can do this:

- create a second array
- create a hash of the current dataset/row
- check this array's keys for the existence of the latest hash using `isset`, [which is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13483219/1456376) than `in_array`
- only if the hash is not found, store it, run `array_combine` on the row and append the result as well

**Result**

```
while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ','))) {
    $hash = md5(serialize($data));

    if (!isset($hashes[$hash])) {
        $hashes[$hash] = true;
        $values[] = array_combine($headerUnique, $data);
    }
}
```

With this improvement the script processes all *36k lines* in **~0.5s** now<sup>*</sup>. Seems a little faster. ;)

---

## Unique entries in the result

Even though this is solved by using the hash now, let me point out a flaw in your logic:

> ```
> if (!in_array($record, $return_waarde)){
>     $return_waarde[] = array_combine($header_trimmed, str_getcsv());
> }
> ```

This will never find any duplicates, because you check for existence of the *indexed* array `$record` but afterwards you insert a different *associative* array.

---

## Unique header names

In the beginning you create unique names for duplicate entries in the header row:

> ```
> if(!in_array($value, $header_trimmed)){
>       $header_trimmed[] = $trim;
>   } else {
>       $header_trimmed[] = $trim . "1";
>   }
> ```

If you have a column name more than two times, you'll end up with this, probably unintended, result:

```
['column', 'column1', 'column1']
```

You can create a function to make the names truly unique, e.g.:

```
function unique_columns(array $columns):array {
    $values = [];

    foreach ($columns as $value) {
        $count = 0;
        $value = $original = trim($value);

        while (in_array($value, $values)) {
            $value = $original . '-' . ++$count;
        }

        $values[] = $value;    
    }

    return $values;
}
```

This will result in

```
['column', 'column-1', 'column-2']
```

---

## Return value of `read_cvs`

Currently your function `read_csv()` does return either a `string` or an `array`. The function should always return an `array`. You can even make the parameter- and return-value-types more strict:

```
function read_csv(string $file): array {}
```

Also try to exit early, when something went wrong instead of nesting `if`-statements. If you actually want to do something, if an error occurs, throw an exception:

```
if (!$file) {
    throw new Exception('File not found: ' . file);
}
```

---

## Final result

Finally let's make this function more versatile by adding the line length and delimiter as optional parameters.

```
function read_csv(string $file, int $length = 1000, string $delimiter = ','): array {
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    $hashes = [];
    $values = [];
    $header = null;
    $headerUnique = null;

    if (!$handle) {
        return $values;
    }

    $header = fgetcsv($handle, $length, $delimiter);

    if (!$header) {
        return $values;
    }

    $headerUnique = unique_columns($header);

    while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($handle, $length, delimiter))) {
        $hash = md5(serialize($data));

        if (!isset($hashes[$hash])) {
            $hashes[$hash] = true;
            $values[] = array_combine($headerUnique, $data);
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);

    return $values;
}
```

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> For testing I used an example CSV-file with over 36.000 lines from the site [SpatialKey](https://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/). I duplicated a few column names and added at least one duplicate line. My environment is the latest MAMP running PHP 7.1.1. The time was measured using: `$start = microtime(true); $x = read_csv('test.csv'); print microtime(true) - $start;`.</sub>